# What happens to a Java program when you turn the power off?

Tags: java

What happens within a Java application running locally on a PC when the power is switched off?(Plug pulled from wall).

Does Java have a way of handling an event like this or is it simply wiped from memory as soon as the power is killed?

Edit: To be a bit more clear, I'm wondering if Java as any way of safely exiting an application in the last moments of an unexpected shutdown.

Comment: What do you expect Java to do when the CPU literally has no power?

Comment: It moves to a farm upstate, with Lassie.

Comment: That would imply that Java itself had some way of working around a power outage

Comment: Your question isn't really limited to a Java program.  If the state of the PC isn't persisted somewhere, i.e. the registers, RAM, etc. are all wiped, then the Java app would be wiped too.

Comment: Write this: `if(!System.getPower()){...}` ;)

Comment: How would java do that "safe exiting" in the event of literally no power in the system? Software cannot act as an emergency standby generator and produce electricity to run anything on the system. If there is no power then the system is dead.

Comment: *I'm wondering if Java as any way of safely exiting an application in the last moments of an unexpected shutdown.* No. When power is removed the entire computer stops; there is no software mechanism to do anything when there is no hardware running to execute it. What happens to your light bulbs when the power goes out? Do they continue to emit light? Why not?

Comment: You didn't specify which Java version 
:D

Comment: Consider using `try-finally()`

Comment: I think I know the answer but it's valid only for ideally spherical computers in the vacuum.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Java programs (like all programs) require a CPU and memory to operate instructions. Both elements are complex electrical circuits, they cannot work without electricity.

The only thing you can do to persist the state of your application, is to write information regarding that state to disc. The [Google File System](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//archive/gfs-sosp2003.pdf) uses this method to ensure not too much information is lost if one of their (usually inexpensive machines) goes down.

Short of this. No there is no way Java can handle a power out.